# Ansible role implies another role

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have Ansible roles A and B. When A is applied to a server, B is also applied. Currently I'm specifying this manually, but this is error prone, so when I add a server I could add role A and forget role B. Is there a way to do this automatically?

I know that a solution would be dependencies. But if I say that A depends on B, then B will be applied first. This is not what I want, B should be applied last.

Comment: you should include one role inside other  role

Comment: Make B depend on A... Obher approach: create role C which simply include role A and B and apply role C.